# Visual Basic 2008 / VB.NET - finding / accessing List item

Tags: vb.net

I was a senior software engineer 14 years ago, working exclusively in VB6. I'm trying to refresh my skills, and I'm now using VB 2008 Express.

I thought a card game would be an excellent way to start refreshing my skills.  What I have is 60 possible positions of a specific card , an array of 8 columns and an additional 8 card docking spots.  The cards are stored in those columns, as items in a Generic VB List of Card (think cards.dll from Win XP)

The only unique properties of the 52 cards that I can use to locate the specific card, are the card value, and the Windows Handle of the specific card object.

So, my question is: can I directly retrieve a specific card, using either the card value, or the Win Handle, without having to loop through the 52 cards to find the specific card ??

TIA !!

Bill

Comment: not being funny, but if you want to refresh your skills wouldn't it make more sense to use a newer version of the language that isn't almost 10 years old? Visual Studio 2017 community edition is free to download and you can use the very latest version of VB.NET.

Comment: Refresh your skills by looking at the various collection types supported in vb.net (like Dictionary) and Linq.

Comment: Both good ideas, and I will move to a newer version of Express.  Just thought that the first version AFTER something I'd used for a long time, would be a good place to start.  Besides, I already had the VB 2008 laying around !! And Hans, YES, I could keep my own index to the objects, as they are created, using Dictionary or the like.  It just seems that I should be able to directly address the object, using its Win Handle.

Comment: technically I believe the first VB.NET version after VB6 was in .NET 1.0 which was released in 2002. But that's long dead, so don't even go there. But the newer versions in the last few years have got a lot more useful features that make coding quicker once you get used to them, so yeah it's not a bad idea to make the leap.

Comment: I removed my answer on behalf of @janes abou chleih.   While I did post the code to get a handle to an object, it was not the specific object you're referring to.

Comment: Jimmy, thanks.  I have the handle, just trying to get at the object that the handle refers to.  Currently, I'm just looping through the possible objects, until I find the one that matches the property I'm trying to find.  As there are always less than 60 of these objects, and needing to search is not very often, there is little impact on the program's performance.